# Java regex for specific pattern

Tags: java, regex

I haven't done anything much with regex so I need some help.

Can anyone tell me how to make regex for such string:

```
/7slDas/
```

Starts with forward slash, than it could be any number or letter(both upper and lower case)

Comment: Only 6 characters between the clashes?

Comment: No, any number of characters. Seems that I managet to do it myself like this:  `"^\\/.+"`  Would this be ok? I just need to test if it starts with `/` and after slash that there are atleast one character. I dont care, number or letter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java you can use this regex:

```
"^/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/?$"
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on the other answers-  you can use this to find that EXACT pattern in the text regardless if the pattern is at the beginning of the text or somewhere in the middle:
    [/][a-zA-Z0-9]+[/]

if you want to find at the beginning of a line add a caret ^ at the beginning of the expression. To find and at the end of the line use the dollar sign at the end of the expression